# Laravel 4.2- How to Route to files in a Subfolder

Tags: laravel

This is my first time using stackoverflow. I am really stuck on a seemingly simple problem in Laravel 4.2, how to route to a bunch of files(.php view files in a subdirectory.

I have about forty .blade.php files in a subdirectory called mechanics.
When the clicks on the link

`action('PagesController@mechanicspages')` (Note: I don't know how to pass a value from here). The route is

```
Route::get('/mechanics/{id}', 'PagesController@mechanicspages');
```

The function at the PagesController is:

```
public function mechanicspages($id)
{
    return View::make('/mechanics/{$id}');
}
```

Can I show a view with this logic?

Comment: I answered below... Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to use the find the object and send it to the view...

To access a view in a subfolder you just use a period "."

Here is what I would do:

*Route file:*

```
Route::get('/mechanics/{id}', 'PagesController@mechanicspages');
```

*Controller File:*

```
public function mechanicspages($id) { 
      $mechanic = Mechanics::find($id);
      if($mechanic)
           return View::make('mechanics.subview')->with($mechanic); 
}
```

For more on this see:

How to pass data to view.
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses  (half way down. Search for "with")

Comment: Thanks for accepting this as the answer... Did you get everything figured out?

Comment: Cool... if you run into any more issues hit me up on Twitter. I love Laravel and up for helping others if they need it.  @jpsmith1981